# AWS Organizations CreateAccount automation with nodeJs Lambdas not creating Account. No error messages, no error logs in CloudWatch. How to solve?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-organizations, aws-control-tower

I am using `AWS Nodejs Lambda` to automate the `Create Account` process inside `AWS Organizations` and using `Serverless` framework to deploy the lambda.

Following is the `Serverless.yml`:

```
functions:
  fnPostOrganizations:
    name: fnPostOrganizations 
    handler: src/Organizations/fnPostOrganizations.fnPostOrganizations
    events:
     - http:
         path: /organizations/create_account
         method: POST
         request:
            parameters:
              querystrings:
                name: true
                token: false
                orgUnit: true
    memorySize: 256
    timeout: 900
    logRetentionInDays: 1
    iamRoleStatementsName: fnPostOrganizations-${self:provider.stage}
    iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - 'organizations:*'
      Resource: '*'
```

The `querystrings` parameters are not important for now. One possible issue here is the `iamRoleStatements` that allows the Lambda to create an Account in the Organization. But if that was the case I should get an error log saying `not authorized` or something like that. That is not happening.

And following is the actual code that should create the Organizations Account using `NodeJs-16x` and SDK V3:

```
'use strict'

const { OrganizationsClient, CreateAccountCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-organizations")
const client = new OrganizationsClient({ region: "us-east-1" });
console.log(' client', client)


const postOrganizationsCreateAccount = async () => {
  try {
    console.log(' START postOrganizationsCreateAccount')

    const params = {
      AccountName: 'testIg',
      Email: `awsTestIg@test.com`,
      IamUserAccessToBilling: 'DENY'
    }
    console.log(' params', params)

    const command = new CreateAccountCommand(params)
    console.log(' command', command)

    const createAccountResponse = await client.send(command)
    console.log(' createAccountResponse', createAccountResponse)
    
    return createAccountResponse
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(' postOrganizationsCreateAccount - error.stack:', error.stack)
    return error.stack
  }
}
```

I am following the [Organizations Client - AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-organizations/index.html) in order to create de account.

Following is the output in the Cloudwacth logs:

```
2022-10-16T17:14:50.989Z    undefined   INFO     client OrganizationsClient {
  middlewareStack: {
    add: [Function: add],
    addRelativeTo: [Function: addRelativeTo],
    clone: [Function: clone],
    use: [Function: use],
    remove: [Function: remove],
    removeByTag: [Function: removeByTag],
    concat: [Function: concat],
    applyToStack: [Function: cloneTo],
    identify: [Function: identify],
    resolve: [Function: resolve]
  },
  config: {
    apiVersion: '2016-11-28',
    disableHostPrefix: false,
    logger: {},
    regionInfoProvider: [AsyncFunction: defaultRegionInfoProvider],
    serviceId: 'Organizations',
    urlParser: [Function: parseUrl],
    region: [AsyncFunction: region],
    runtime: 'node',
    defaultsMode: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    base64Decoder: [Function: fromBase64],
    base64Encoder: [Function: toBase64],
    bodyLengthChecker: [Function: calculateBodyLength],
    credentialDefaultProvider: [Function (anonymous)],
    defaultUserAgentProvider: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    maxAttempts: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    requestHandler: NodeHttpHandler { metadata: [Object], configProvider: [Promise] },
    retryMode: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    sha256: [Function: bound Hash],
    streamCollector: [Function: streamCollector],
    useDualstackEndpoint: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    useFipsEndpoint: [AsyncFunction: useFipsEndpoint],
    utf8Decoder: [Function: fromUtf8],
    utf8Encoder: [Function: toUtf8],
    tls: true,
    endpoint: [Function (anonymous)],
    isCustomEndpoint: false,
    retryStrategy: [AsyncFunction: retryStrategy],
    systemClockOffset: 0,
    signingEscapePath: true,
    credentials: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    signer: [Function: signer],
    customUserAgent: undefined
  }
}

2022-10-16T17:14:50.995Z    91b515e5-aa3c-4eb1-a6ba-7d12fd0beef5    INFO     START postOrganizationsCreateAccount

2022-10-16T17:14:50.995Z    91b515e5-aa3c-4eb1-a6ba-7d12fd0beef5    INFO     params {
  AccountName: 'testIg',
  Email: 'awsTestIg@test.com',
  IamUserAccessToBilling: 'DENY'
}
2022-10-16T17:14:50.996Z    91b515e5-aa3c-4eb1-a6ba-7d12fd0beef5    INFO     command CreateAccountCommand {
  middlewareStack: {
    add: [Function: add],
    addRelativeTo: [Function: addRelativeTo],
    clone: [Function: clone],
    use: [Function: use],
    remove: [Function: remove],
    removeByTag: [Function: removeByTag],
    concat: [Function: concat],
    applyToStack: [Function: cloneTo],
    identify: [Function: identify],
    resolve: [Function: resolve]
  },
  input: {
    AccountName: 'testIg',
    Email: 'awsTestIg@test.com',
    IamUserAccessToBilling: 'DENY'
  }
}
END RequestId: 91b515e5-aa3c-4eb1-a6ba-7d12fd0beef5
REPORT RequestId: 91b515e5-aa3c-4eb1-a6ba-7d12fd0beef5  Duration: 145.74 ms Billed Duration: 146 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 82 MB  Init Duration: 414.12 ms
```

It seems that everything is going well until the moment when it sends the command `await client.send(command)`. After that point I do not have any log output. No `error` as well.

If I use `AWS CLI` to perform the same process I get the following:

command:
`aws organizations create-account --email testIgn@example.com --account-name "testIgName" --iam-user-access-to-billing "DENY"`

output:

```
  {
      "CreateAccountStatus": {
          "Id": "car-b4be21e04bfwert6wdgf",
          "AccountName": "testIgName",
          "State": "IN_PROGRESS",
          "RequestedTimestamp": "2022-10-14T15:59:26.737000-04:00"
      }
  }
```

And the account is created in the Organizations.

At the `CreateAccountCommand` [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-organizations/classes/createaccountcommand.html) it says:

```
Because CreateAccount operates asynchronously, it can return a successful completion message even though account initialization might still be in progress. You might need to wait a few minutes before you can successfully access the account...
```

But even if it is an asynchronous process I should get a `CreateAccountResponse` by this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-organizations/interfaces/createaccountcommandoutput.html).

At this point I don't know what is happening or how to solve this issue. Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide the whole contents of the lambda function are you exporting it as `async`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the Lambda handler function as `async`.

```js
// ...your code above
exports.handler = async function(event) {
  try {
    const createAccountResponse = await postOrganizationsCreateAccount(event);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: 'Account created'
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: error.message
    };
  }
}
```